# Python get module to save to its own folder rather than folder of the file accessing it

Tags: python, python-module

Right now, I have a module with a file (and class) memoizer.py, called by a file tutorial2.py.  Memoizer has a method where it specifies a file name, say "package.txt", and creates that file using open.  When I run it, it creates the file in the folder of tutorial2.py.  How do I get it to create it in either the folder of memoizer.py, or a subfolder of the folder containing memoizer.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__file__` module attribute:

```
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'package.txt'), 'w'):
    pass
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Modules
>
> ...
>
> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file.